# C#: keep the timer running even after the end of the method

Tags: c#, timer

Any idea how can I keep the timer running even after the method ends

```
public static void Method(){
    Timer Timer = new Timer(state: null, dueTime: 0, period: 60000, callback: (o) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you <3");
    });
}
```

The code above displays something like this:

```
1. Thank you <3
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
1. Thank you <3 (after 0 min)
2. Thank you <3 (after 1 min)
3. Thank you <3 (after 2 min)
4. ...
```

I tried `GC.KeepAlive(Timer);` but doesn't seem to work.

I know this is related to the garbage collector, and I can work around this and create Timer as a global variable, but are there any better suggestions?

Comment: If you need to make a new timer every time you call that method, it would likely be best to keep rooted reference to it in the instance, or if you need multiple timers, in a list and remove it when you disable it so it can be collected

Comment: This method will only be called once, any suggestions?

Comment: Move the Timer declaration outside the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I can work around this and create Timer as a global variable

That's exactly what you should do...move the Timer declaration to outside the method:

```
private static Timer timer;

public static void Method(){
    timer = new Timer(state: null, dueTime: 0, period: 60000, callback: (o) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you <3");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have created a static Timer List in a global file so that I can call: `Global.Timers.Add(new Timer (...))` and keep any Timer I want running without being deleted by the Garbage Collector. Anyway, your answer is right. I just want to make sure by obtaining new perspectives.